# Curl is working on machine but not on web browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, curl

I created a simple nodejs app on the aws-ec2 server following the instructions. The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs

var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res)
 {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080, '138.68.244.XXX');   
//138.68.244.XXX is the IP of my ec2 server
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8080/');
```

After I started the app by the command: `node hello.js`

I got output:

> Server running at http://localhost:8080/

I was able to curl the URL:

`curl http://138.68.244.XXX:8080`

to get “Hello World” on the server itself, however, when I tried:

`http://138.68.244.XXX:8080`

in a browser, I got:

> ERRCONNECTIONTIMED_OUT

Please help,
Thank you!

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `docker`? Is the NodeJS app running in a Docker container?

Comment: Is that public instance? It seems to be. How about Security Groups? Is port 8080 opened for inbound connections?

Comment: yes 8080 port is open in my ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this FAQ entry](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/) (how to open a port on an instance with a public IP). As port 8080 is not a standard HTTP port, you probably need to update the security group and ACL.

Comment: How docker is linked to my server the connectivity of docker is with the docker hub which makes it a global service?So what is the use of ec2 ports?